Is there something similar to an exponentially modified gaussian distribution that goes in the opposite direction?
$f(x; \mu, \sigma, \lambda, A) = A \cdot e^{\left( A \left( 2\mu + \lambda\sigma^2 - 2x \right) \right)} \cdot \text{erfc}\left( \frac{\mu + \lambda\sigma^2 - x}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \right)$
I'm not too comfortable with statistical mathematics but I am writing an algorithm to understand histogram data yet my data sometimes has extended tails moving to the left instead of the right. This function only works to model rightward facing tails. I'm having trouble finding a useable algorithm that can still apply as a gaussian distribution just also having the ability to account for tails to the left. It has to ba gaussian or at least similar enough to where I can still get a sigma, lambda, and mu to use in calculations later on.

Please don't add pictures of formulae, just write them, using MathJax notation.

woah we can write them in here? hold on I'm going to try it out

thank you so much for that, hope this edit is detailed enough

Skew normal distribution allows for both cases.
